# Graph a single LDA topic by date (in R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, lda, topic-modeling, topicmodels

I have a group of text files from several journals (let's call them journal A and journal B) that I am trying to run LDA on. I divide them each into their own corpus, then attach the names of the files to each corpus, store the journal of origin under the `origin` label, and finally, combine the two corpuses into `myCorpus`:

```
library(tm); library(topicmodels);

txtfolder <- "~/Path/to/txtfiles/"
source <- DirSource(txtfolder)
A.names <- list.files(path=txtfolder, pattern="A")
B.names <- list.files(path=txtfolder, pattern="B")
A.names <- lapply(X=A.names, FUN=function(i){gsub(".txt", '', x=i)})
B.names <- lapply(X=B.names, FUN=function(i){gsub(".txt", '', x=i)})
A.corpus <- Corpus(A.source, readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))
for (i in 1:length(A.corpus)){
  meta(A.corpus[[i]], tag = "origin") <- "A"
}
B.corpus <- Corpus(B.source, readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))
for (i in 1:length(B.corpus)){
  meta(B.corpus[[i]], tag = "origin") <- "B"
}
myCorpus <- c(A.corpus, B.corpus) # combining the two corpuses
```

From here I run LDA on `myCorpus`:

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(minWordLength=3))
n.topics <- 5
lda.model <- LDA(dtm, n.topics)
terms(lda.model,10)
```

From here I would like to create a plot measuring the proportion of each journal that is due to a particular topic over time (I can identify the time that each issue of the journals was published by parsing the txt files, and store them in a vector similarly to how I did with the `origin` tag). I'm not sure how best to store this information so that I can use date published as the horizontal axis. More importantly, how can I create the graph that I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use `ggplot` since you added this tag. You will first need to gather your data in a data frame.

Assuming `lda` is the output of `LDA()` and `corpus` is the corpus, you'll find the topics with `topics(lda)` and the various informations on the documents using `meta(corpus)`. You might need to adjust this to your corpus :

```
df <- data.frame(id=names(topics(lda)),
                 topic=topics(lda),
                 date=as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(meta(corpus,type="local",tag="datetimestamp"),as.character))),
                 origin=unlist(meta(corpus,type="local",tag="origin"))    )
```

Then, you need to compute the stats you want to plot : the frequency of each topic by date and by origin, and

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
M <- df %>% gather(key,value,topic) %>%
  group_by(date,origin,value) %>%
  summarize(n=n()) %>%
  mutate(f=n/sum(n))
```

Finally, in order to plot it :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=M,aes(x=date,fill=factor(value),y=f)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack") +
  facet_grid(~origin)
```

Here is what it gives with simulated data

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(date=sample(seq.Date(as.Date("2015-07-27 10:12:25"),as.Date("2015-07-31 10:12:25"),by=1),100,replace=TRUE),
       id=1:100,
       topic=sample(1:5,100,replace=TRUE),
       origin=sample(c("A","B"),100,replace=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great @scoa ! There's just one thing I haven't been able to figure out - when I use `topics(lda)`, I get only a single topic for each issue of A and B - how can I get that topic makeup? Also, how could I measure the proportion of each journal due to a single topic (in a line graph probably)? I'm mostly just unsure how to isolate a single topic.

Comment: @mlinegar you can access those with `posterior(lda)$topics`. `cbind(df,posterior(lda)$topics)` should work. Your second question is too much for the comments. Could you edit your question or ask a new one with the output you want?

Comment: you're definitely right that I need to revisit the second question I posted, but I've gotten stuck working with the dataframes on the way there. With `df` defined as you did, I then use `td <- posterior(lda)$topics` and `dfr <- cbind(df,td)` which gives me `Warning message: In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) :  some row.names duplicated: 2,3, ...`. If I ignore the error and graph anyway, I get the same problem I did earlier. Again, thank you so much for your help!